# Sum same values in different columns (Google Spreadsheet)

Tags: google-sheets

I've got two columns, A with the date and B with the revenue. Some dates are duplicated and I'd like to omit the duplicate dates and to sum the revenue values from the same date.

It would be something like bringing this:

```
12/04/2014  5$
12/04/2014  5$
13/04/2014  6$
13/04/2014  6$
```

to this:

```
12/04/2014  10$
13/04/2014  12$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`query`](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/3093343) to achieve this. If your data is in columns `A` & `B` with headers, you could use:

```
=Query($A$1:$B$5,"select A,sum(B) group by A", 1)
```

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gcSHJ2e333RPEt4lJXP11sBEnNHXMEy5YY_KPolDUEg/edit?usp=sharing) is a sample sheet.

Answer (score 1):

You also can use:

`=unique(A)`, this will return each date

`=sum(filter(B:B,A=date_row)`, sum each time that date appears

I hope it works for you!
Regards